# How to accomplish parameterized subcircuits in LTSpice?

Tags: simulation, inverter, cmos, ltspice

I am trying to play around with beta ratio effect of CMOS inverter. To do so I need to have parameterized subcircuit so I can adjust the ratio of PMOS beta over NMOS beta and achieve HI-skewed or LO-skewed inverters.

How do you define parameter `x` in a sub-circuit?

What I need to do is to define a sub-circuit like this:

```
.subckt inverter_035_x in out VDD GND
XM1 out in 0 0 NM W={x*1u} L=0.35u
XM2 out in VDD VDD PM W={x*3u} L=0.35u
.ends inverter_035_x
```

and then set `x` in every instance of the subcircuit so I can achieve different transistor width per instance.

How to set `x` and pass it to a sub-circuit instance?

Comment: ok I figured it out. Just needed to right click and type 'x=2' in PARAM field from the main block to pass the x set 2 to the sub-circuit.

Comment: Make that comment an answer instead and mark it as answered.

Comment: ok I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I figured it out. Just needed to right click and type 'x=2' in PARAM field from the main block to pass the x set 2 to the sub-circuit.